# Function error with rollapply

Tags: r

I'm trying to pass a window over some columns of data with `rollapply`. If the conditions are met in the function (JRip) then I'd like each row of the output dataframe to display the predicted `Behaviour`.

Here is the code so far:

```
library(zoo)
# This is the matrix for the results of the function
Predicted <- matrix() # matrix to store model results



Out <- structure(list(latitude_position_1 = c("91.1227553646932", "91.1227518740347", 
"91.1227483833762", "91.1227483833762", "91.1227483833762",   "91.1227483833762"
), longtude_position_1 = c("-6.23305421507455", "-6.2330489790868", 
"-6.23304374309904", "-6.23303850711129", "-6.23304374309904", 
"-6.2330489790868"), latitude_position_2 = c("91.1227518740347", 
"91.1227483833762", "91.1227483833762", "91.1227483833762", "91.1227483833762", 
"91.1227483833762"), longtude_position_2 = c("-6.2330489790868", 
"-6.23304374309904", "-6.23303850711129", "-6.23304374309904", 
"-6.2330489790868", "-6.2330559604038"), Distance = c("0.400505694328303", 
"0.400505709727528", "0.333912980750125", "0.333912980750125", 
"0.333912980750125", "0.445217307591311"), Speed = c("0.03", 
"0.155", "0.155", "0.09", "0.275", "0.275"), Acceleration = c("0.012", 
"0.038", "-0.038", "0.012", "0.062", "-0.062"), Absolute_Heading =     c("236.306305752159", 
"236.306307393042", "270.000002484092", "89.9999975159082", "89.9999975159082", 
"89.9999966878713"), Relative_Heading = c("-236.306305752159", 
"-1.64088351084501e-06", "-33.6936950910497", "180.000004968184", 
"0", "8.28036945677013e-07"), Movement = c("left", "forward", 
"forward", "non-moving", "non-moving", "non-moving"), Changes = c("0", 
"1", "0", "1", "0", "0"), Transition = c("****", "****", "****", 
"Transition", "****", "****")), .Names = c("latitude_position_1", 
"longtude_position_1", "latitude_position_2", "longtude_position_2", 
"Distance", "Speed", "Acceleration", "Absolute_Heading", "Relative_Heading", 
"Movement", "Changes", "Transition"), row.names = c("0.1", "0.2", 
"0.3", "0.4", "0.5", "0.6"), class = "data.frame")



# Here are the columns of the dataframe I'd like to run the window over
Dist_Out <- (Out[, 5])
Speed_Out <- (Out[, 6])
Acceleration_Out <- (Out[, 7])
Absolute_Heading_Out <- (Out[, 8])
Relative_Heading_Out <- (Out[, 9])
Movement_Out <- (Out[, 10])
Changes_Out <- (Out[, 11])

# this is the object for the function
Behaviour <- JRip(Dist_Out, Speed_Out, Acceleration_Out, Absolute_Heading_Out, Relative_Heading_Out, Movement_Out, Changes_Out)

rollapply(Out, width = 2, FUN = Behaviour, by = 1, ascending = FALSE, by.column = FALSE, align = c("center"))


# this is the function
JRip <- function(Dist_Out, Speed_Out, Acceleration_Out, Absolute_Heading_Out, Relative_Heading_Out, Movement_Out, Changes_Out)
{
  # walking
  if (max(Speed_Out) >= 2.45)  Behaviour <- "walking"  else Behaviour <- "resting"

  return (Behaviour)
}


# output 'behaviour' as dataframe.
Predicted <- as.data.frame(Behaviour)
```

However, I'm getting this error at the moment:

```
Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
  object 'resting' of mode 'function' was not found
```

The function is in its infancy because I want to make sure this works before I add all the other elements of the function. The function is also called up using `source` so doesn't appear in the code as above.

Here is some of the 'Out' input:

```
latitude_position_1 longtude_position_1 latitude_position_2 longtude_position_2          Distance Speed Acceleration Absolute_Heading       Relative_Heading   Movement Changes Transition
1     91.1227553646932   -6.23305421507455    91.1227518740347    -6.2330489790868 0.400505694328303  0.03        0.012 236.306305752159     -236.306305752159       left       0       ****
2     91.1227518740347    -6.2330489790868    91.1227483833762   -6.23304374309904 0.400505709727528 0.155        0.038 236.306307393042 -1.64088351084501e-06    forward       1       ****
3     91.1227483833762   -6.23304374309904    91.1227483833762   -6.23303850711129 0.333912980750125 0.155       -0.038 270.000002484092     -33.6936950910497    forward       0       ****
4     91.1227483833762   -6.23303850711129    91.1227483833762   -6.23304374309904 0.333912980750125  0.09        0.012 89.9999975159082      180.000004968184 non-moving       1 Transition
5     91.1227483833762   -6.23304374309904    91.1227483833762    -6.2330489790868 0.333912980750125 0.275        0.062 89.9999975159082                     0 non-moving       0       ****
6     91.1227483833762    -6.2330489790868    91.1227483833762    -6.2330559604038 0.445217307591311 0.275       -0.062 89.9999966878713    8.28036945677013e-07 non-moving       0       ****
7     91.1227483833762    -6.2330559604038    91.1227431473884   -6.23304548842829 0.745675662288711  0.12            0 243.431811475523     -153.431814787652       left       1       ****
8     91.1227431473884   -6.23304548842829    91.1227448927177   -6.23304374309904 0.156892934292016 0.275        0.062 315.003927795227     -71.5721163197041 non-moving       1       ****
9     91.1227448927177   -6.23304374309904    91.1227536193639   -6.23306468705007  1.44555679702924  0.31       -0.048 67.3773348964212      247.626592898806      right       1       ****
10    91.1227536193639   -6.23306468705007    91.1227536193639   -6.23306643237932 0.111304317308227 0.155       -0.014 89.9999991716402     -22.6226642752191    forward       1       ****
11    91.1227536193639   -6.23306643237932    91.1227588553517   -6.23306643237932 0.331723741058604 0.155        0.014                0      89.9999991716402 non-moving       1       ****
12    91.1227588553517   -6.23306643237932    91.1227623460102   -6.23306643237932  0.22114916222707  0.19            0                0                     0 non-moving       0       ****
13    91.1227623460102   -6.23306643237932    91.1227606006809   -6.23306468705007 0.156892912024679 0.405        0.086 224.996065562981     -224.996065562981 non-moving       0       ****
14    91.1227606006809   -6.23306468705007    91.1227693273272    -6.2330559604038 0.784464537327535 0.465       -0.062  315.00394101503     -90.0078754520491       left       1       ****
15    91.1227693273272    -6.2330559604038    91.1227763086442   -6.23305945106231 0.495158944897039  0.31            0  26.561897224065      288.442043790965      right       1       ****
16    91.1227763086442   -6.23305945106231    91.1227763086442   -6.23306468705007 0.333912827211437 0.215       -0.038 89.9999975116924     -63.4381002876273       left       1       ****
17    91.1227763086442   -6.23306468705007    91.1227728179857   -6.23306992303782 0.400505598712409 0.155        0.014 123.693703315054     -33.6937058033612    forward       1       ****
```

I need to run a window of width '32' to pass the function over all of these columns at once. For example:

"if the speed in the first 32 rows is >= 2.45 then label all rows as 'walking, ' and then continue through the dataset in groups of 32.

I hope this helps with the error I'm getting. Thanks

Comment: The function is `JRip`, not `Behaviour`, right? And it should be defined before you use it.

Comment: Yes the function is 'JRip', but termed by object 'Behaviour.' As I said in the post, the function doesn't appear as above, it is called in to the program from source. Thanks.

Comment: Then you have a typo in your question. You speak about the function `Behaviour`. Thanks

Comment: My apologies, then the function is infact 'JRip.' Thanks for that.

Comment: The question still stands though ;)

Comment: Questions to SO should have reproducible code including all inputs so readers can copy it from the question and paste it into their serssion and see the same result you see.

Comment: Use `dput(Out)` or if too long `Out <- head(Out); dput(Out)` and change `width` so it makes sense with the smaller input.  Also fix your code so that the only error it gives is the one you are reporting on.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Where should I use dput and why?

Comment: Also, the above input is a smaller example of the input, but if you adjust width to accommodate the example then you will see the same error?

Comment: Type `Out <- head(Out); dput(Out)` into R and then in the question write `Out <-` followed by the output from `dput` and put all that at a point in your question that is prior to the first use of `Out`. That will make the question reproducible. Then modify `width` so it makes sense with the smaller set of input data and still gives the error you are reporting on and also test your code to ensure that it does not give other errors first (which it currently does).  For example, someone has already pointed out that JRip is used prior to defining it so this needs to be fixed, etc.